# Set Pie Chart into a JLabel instead of new frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jfreechart

I write a code that can show pie chart by a new frame, but i want to show that chart into a **label**

My code is

```
DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        pieDataset.setValue("Bangla 1st",new Integer(txt_Bangla1st.getText()));
        pieDataset.setValue("Bangla 2nd",new Integer(txt_Bangla2nd.getText()));
        pieDataset.setValue("English 1st",new Integer(txt_English1st.getText()));
        pieDataset.setValue("English 2nd",new Integer(txt_English2nd.getText()));
        pieDataset.setValue("Math",new Integer(txt_Math.getText()));
        pieDataset.setValue("Social Science",new Integer(txt_Social.getText()));
        pieDataset.setValue("Science",new Integer(txt_Science.getText()));
        pieDataset.setValue("Religion",new Integer(txt_Religion.getText()));

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Pie Chart", pieDataset, true, true, true);
        PiePlot p = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Pie Chart", chart);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setSize(400, 500); //show frame size
```

Set the chart into a label which variable name is **lblPichartAndBarchart**.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: set the pie chart into a jLabel @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: `"set the pie chart into a jLabel"` -- That's not a question; that's a requirement. You're not showing any ChartFrame code, you're not telling us what problems you're having.

Comment: I already mention it the chart is showing by a new frame,,but i want to show that into a jLabel

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sir, Did you get my question ?

Comment: *"Did you get my question ?"*  That is the first question I've seen.  As mentioned by @HovercraftFullOfEels, the earlier comments were simply (restating) the requirement.  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  If there is a solution to be found to a question like *"How to display the pie chart in a label in the **existing** GUI?"* (which is what I **guess** the question might be) it will be suggested in the current code (but make it an MCVE we can work with).

Answer (score 2):

It seems in this case that the functionality can be provided by using a [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) instead of the `ChartFrame`.

- Create a `ChartPanel` and add it somewhere in the main top level container (usually a `JFrame`).
- When it comes time to update the chart, call [`ChartPanel.setChart(JFreeChart)`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setChart-org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart-).